# Have you tried Class AudioTrack in Android with a buffer size which is a power of two?

Tags: android, exception

I'm working in one application for Android with class AudioTrack, and sometimes I get the exception "Invalid audio buffer size". Since I'm planning to use FFT, I make the buffer size a power of two, and since then, sometimes I get this exception. Any ideas why is that?

Thanks,
Daniel

My code is very straight forward:

```
private void playTrack(short []buffer){
        try{
            Log.i(TAG,"Play track, Buffer size: "+buffer.length );
            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    mAudioIn.getFrequency(),
                    mAudioIn.getChannelConfig(),
                    mAudioIn.getAudioEncoding(),
                    buffer.length,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
            audioTrack.play();

            audioTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        }catch(Throwable t){
            Log.e(TAG,"Play track, something's wrong: "+t.getMessage()+ " When buffer size is:"+buffer.length );
        }

    }`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 3):

I just realized, you can't use an odd number as the buffer size. Try taking your size and doing something like this:

```
if (size % 2 == 1)
    size++;`
```

This will make an odd number even.

Comment: Yes the docs say that the buffer size needs to be a multiple of the frame size. But the docs never explain what a "frame" is.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling something like

```
_audioTrackSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(
            audioSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
```

and then round the returned minimum size up to a power of two.